# PyInstaller Issues + Errno 2

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Fairly new to coding and I'm taking on a project to analyze data from an Excel sheet and output several plots. When I run the script in Sublime 3 as a .py it's flawless and takes no more than 30 seconds. I tried converting it from .py to .exe via PyInstaller and I keep running into the same issue:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 887, in apply_default_cascade
  File "site-packages\plotly\io\_templates.py", line 89, in __getitem__
  File "pkgutil.py", line 637, in get_data
  File "c:\users\shaba\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 471, in get_data
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\shaba\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI133402\\plotly\\package_data\\templates\\plotly.json'**

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
  File "SHProject.py", line 53, in fp
  File "SHProject.py", line 107, in project
  File "site-packages\plotly\express\_chart_types.py", line 1186, in density_mapbox
  File "site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 1829, in make_figure
  File "site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 890, in apply_default_cascade
  File "site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\layout\_template.py", line 306, in __init__
**ValueError: The first argument to the plotly.graph_objs.layout.Template
constructor must be a dict or
an instance of :class:`plotly.graph_objs.layout.Template**
```

Right now, I'm more interested in the first bolded error, but the ValueError below will probably be an issue too. I tried making a new folder and copy/pasting the plotly.json file there and putting the new folder's absolute path into the data=[] in the .spec via Sublime 3 but every time the path it's looking for it in is changing?

Literally everything is working perfectly except for compiling it into an exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file called `hook-plotly.py`, and place it in a directory `hooks`, which is next to your script. Like this:

```
- main.py
- hooks
  - hook-plotly.py
```

Then, inside `hook-plotly.py`:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all('plotly')
```

And then build with the command line parameter `--additional-hooks-dir=hooks`.

Comment: WOW! This worked! Thank you so much. It took FOREVER to finish and for whatever reason it takes a few minutes to start up but it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The exe is searching file from C:\Users\shaba\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI133402\plotly\package_data\templates\plotly.json here.

use this method to get exe/Code path in the code and build your filepath, so the file will be searched in the correct folder.

```
import sys
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
elif __file__:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    application_path, ignor = os.path.split(application_path)
```

so in the application path you will get path of this py file or exe.append your json file name and directory to this